# Expandable UITableViewCell overlapping other cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, expand

I'm working on a UITableView with expandable cells and I got it working with:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(_selectedCellIndexPath != nil
   && [_selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
    return 160;

return 40;
}
```

and

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
_selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;

[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

And the UITableViewCell set up in Storyboard as:

[image]

But when I change it to this:

[image]

to add the description and button, it scrambles up everything like this:

[image]

How come the description textview and more info button are showing even though the heightForRowAtIndexPath is 40 and they should be 'hidden'?

Or am I taking a wrong approach to this?

Also, the tapping and expanding is not applied to the searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView. How can I do this?

Edit: cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"IngredientCell";

UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.333];
cell.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UILabel *title = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *summary = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:2];
UIButton *moreInfo = (UIButton*) [cell viewWithTag:3];

summary.hidden = YES;
moreInfo.hidden = YES;

[title setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];

// Display recipe in the table cell
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    [title setText: [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //set summary
} else {
    [title setText: [ingredients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //set summary
}

// Change color if dissallowed
if ([[title text] rangeOfString:@"Egg"].location != NSNotFound) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.350 blue:0.485 alpha:0.333];
}

// Change color when selected
UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = customColorView;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: I would like to know what you did in cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource method

Comment: Added the method for you